# Decay estimate of moment of an SDE

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, moments

We consider an SDE
$$
d X_t = b(t, X_t) \, dt + \sigma(t, X_t) \, d B_t,
$$
where $(B_t)$ is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion on $\mathbb R^d$. We fix $p \in [1, \infty)$. Here $b, \sigma$ are Lipschitz in space uniformly in time.

> Are there decay estimates of moment in a form
> $$
> \sup_{t \in [0, 1]} \mathbb E [ |X_t|^p 1_{\{|X_t| \ge R\}} ] \le \frac{c(1 + \mathbb E [ |X_0|^{p+1} ])}{\varphi (R)},
> \quad \forall R >0 \text{?}
> $$

Above, $\varphi: \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+$ is an increasing function and the constant $c>0$ possibly depends on $d, b, \sigma, p$. Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: The bound should depend, non-multiplicatively, on the Lipschitz constants.

Comment: If by 'increasing' you mean 'increasing to infinity' then it's not even true for $b=\sigma=0$...

Comment: @IosifPinelis Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @MartinHairer the exponent on the RHS should be $p+1$ rather than $p$. I have edited my thread to fix this typo...

Comment: Take e.g. $X_0=0$, $b=1$, $\sigma=0$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis You are right! I have edited my question...

Comment: What do mean, exactly, by $\lesssim$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I am sorry for the inconvenience, I have edited (again) my question for more clarity.

Comment: @Akira But then isn't it just an immediate consequence of Itô's formula applied to a smoothened out version of $x \mapsto |x|^{p+1}$, followed by Hölder and Markov's inequality?

Comment: @MartinHairer Thank you so much for your enlightening comment! I got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we can apply Burkholder-Davis-Gundy to control the supremum of moments, we start by removing the tail simply using $1\leq \frac{|X_{t}|}{R}$.

$$
\mathbb E [ |X_t|^p 1_{\{|X_t| \ge R\}} ]\leq \frac{1}{R}\mathbb E [ |X_t|^{p+1} ].
$$

And then as done in René Schilling, Lothar Partzsch: Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes, Chapter 19 (2nd edition) (see [Application of the Burkholder Davis Gundy inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280256/application-of-the-burkholder-davis-gundy-inequality)) we have the bound

$$\sup_{t\leq T}\mathbb E [ |X_t|^{p+1} ]\leq \mathbb{E}\sup_{t\leq T}|X_t|^{p+1}\leq Ce^{CT}(1+\mathbb{E}|X_0|^{p+1}).$$

Interestingly, note that you can get faster decay by using $1\leq \frac{|X_{t}|^{q}}{R^{q}}$ if you have $\mathbb{E}|X_0|^{p+q}<\infty$.